# How to restrict combobox to show only not-yet-selected items in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, combobox

My question is simple, but I am afraid that there is no solution for this.

1. I want to create 3 combo boxes in 3 lines in a column.
2. The combo boxes have only 3 values.
3. If I select an item from the combo box, then the other two combo boxes should have only the remaining 2 items to select.
4. If I select an item from a second combo box, then the last one should have only the remaining 1 item to select.
5. If I clear the first combo box selection, then the first and last combo boxes should have only the remaining 2 items to select again.

Is this possible somehow in Google Sheets?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

There definitely is a solution for this, you're just going to need some separate formulas.

Reserve 9-12 cells (depending if you want headers) and label them so that you know which dropdown they refer to (i.e. box 1, box 2, box 3).
Under Box 1, simply list your 3 values.
Under Box 2, enter the formula `=filter(C2:C4, A1<>C2:C4)` replacing `C2:C4` with the range of Box 1's three values, and `A1` with the cell of the first dropdown box.
Under Box 3, enter the formula `=filter(D2:D4, A2<>D2:D4)`, replacing `D2:D4` with the range of Box 2's three values, and `A2` with the cell of the second dropdown box.
Now, just insert dropboxes and set the list range to the three ranges from above. The formulas will cause the cell values to change, and in turn change the dropbox values.

And that's it! If you would want them to all be independent, as it seems the last part of your question asks for,(ex. choosing a value in Box 2 first and then Box 1 and 3 changing accordingly) it would just require some longer formulas. I can work on that, but i wanted to get this to you first to be sure this is what you were asking for.

[image: working]

Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YLW7qL685FJjXKPE0uWTM50YhygpOZqK0UW4u48atI/edit?usp=sharing